# highlighting the textbox without using javascript or jquery

Tags: html, jsp-tags

can we highlight our textbox without using javasript/jquery or css ?if yes then how? i am on jsp page, can jsp help?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use CSS?

Comment: yes it is. actually i have to add a component dynamically and once among 30. so dont want to write css or js for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with CSS inline, without using an external stylesheet. If you really must:

```
<input type="text" style="background-color:#FFFFCC;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible without CSS (if you want to use things like colors). You can do it without JavaScript, though. This would be the CSS for doing it:

```
.textbox {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

And the markup:

```
<textarea class="textbox" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: He said without "javascript/jquery or css"

Comment: "without using javasript/jquery or css"

Comment: @Rob Sobers, @Ash Burlaczenko: Sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: can any one write some css to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default style (including color) of an HTML element from the default style that the browser uses, you must apply the style via CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: @MohdAdnan @elusive wrote the CSS for you in his answer.